# Code to Make and Print a Dictionary Containing Input Values Outputs an Incomplete Dictionary; Why?

Tags: python, dictionary, input, conditional-statements

I'm trying to store 5 pairs of user input variables (user name & age) into a dictionary and return that dictionary in a print statement, but it keeps outputting a dictionary with only the last key-value pair. What's going on in the code making this happen?

```
query_count= 0
user_info = {}
for i in range (5):
    query_count = 0
    user_info = {}
    user_info['user'] = input("user: ")
    user_info['age'] = input("age: ")
    query_count += 1
    if query_count < 5:
        continue
print(user_info)
```

example output:

```
{'user': 'Jamie', 'age': '42'}
```

Comment: You are overwriting the dictionary on every iteration.

Comment: try remove "user_info = {}" in the for loop

Comment: Removed "user_info = {}" and still getting the same result. Will be looking for ways to keep it from repeating the overwriting. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U r actually updating the same keys again and again. U can instead use the username as a key and its value as age.

```
user_info = {}
for i in range(5):
   name = input('Enter name:')
   age = int(input('Enter age: '))
   user_info[name] = age
   print('One Entry Taken!') 
print(user_info)
```

I don't think there is any need to print the age & name after every input. Output:

```
{'name1': 1, 'name2': 2, 'name3': 3, 'name4':4, 'name5': 5}
```

A pythonic way to achieve this:

```
user_info = {}
for i in range(5):
    name, user_info[name] = input('Enter name: '), int(input('Enter age: '))
print(user_info)
```

I did not understand the use of query_count in ur logic. Plz elaborate.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great help. There was no real reason for query_count other than my misunderstanding of how to implement an iterative addition of successive input into the dictionary. Your pythonic rendition is a perfectly effective, and an example I will study in contrast to my original. If I wanted to print a message for every user under a given age, would I refer to the user ages in the loop statement as "if user_info[name] < 20, print(...) ?

Comment: u can actually traverse the dictionary, like: for i in user_info... i is the key... user_info[i] is the age so u can write:  if user_info[i] < 20: #ur statement

Comment: Okay, I'll work with doing that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the same fields five times. There is no reference of 'i' which can tell dictionary to iterate. Also dictionary has key value pairs. You can't have one key multiple times. Instead of that you should have entries like "name":"age" say "abc":"23"

Try something like below code:

```
user_info = {}
for i in range (5):
    name = input("user: ")
    print(name)
    age = input("age: ")
    print(age)
    user_info[name] = age
print(user_info)
```

Output: `{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'e': '5'}`

Note that if you enter duplicate name then entry in dictionary will be replaced.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Will try to work with this apply it towards a reformulation of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating same keys in `user_info`, and thus overwriting previous inputs. You should use `list`, and append individual `user_info` dictionary to that list within the loop.
Take a look at following code:

```
users = []
for i in range(5):
   user_info = {}
   user_info['user'] = input("user: ")
   user_info['age'] = input("age: ")
   users.append(user_info)
print(users)
```

Could you please elaborate on purpose of `query_count` logic in your code? I have removed it from the snippet I am posting since, it is not needed if all you want is to get a list of `{'user': 'x', 'age': 'y'}` dictionaries.

Comment: This edition worked. Thank you very much for helping me. ```query_count``` was there basically because I don't fully understand how to implement iterations that occur for a set number of times with the right syntax. This has given me some things to consider. Thank you again.